# Regex replacement for SQL using sed

Tags: regex, sed

I have a file containing many SQL statements and need to add escape characters, using SED, for single quotes withing the SQL statements. Consider the following:

```
INSERT INTO MYTABLE VALUES (1,'some text','Drink at O'Briens');
```

In the above we need to escape the single quote in `O'Briens`. Using regex I can find the string using `[a-zA-Z ]'[a-zA-Z ]`.

So this will find the 3 characters of interest, however if I do the following sed command:

```
sed -i "s/[a-zA-Z ]'[a-zA-Z ]/''/g" file.sql
```

This, however, removes the `O` and the `B` so I end up with:

```
INSERT INTO MYTABLE VALUES (1,'some text','Drink at ''riens');
```

How do I isolate/reference the O and the B so the string becomes:

```
INSERT INTO MYTABLE VALUES (1,'some text','Drink at O''Briens');
```

Comment: Use capture groups and back-references. Isn't that always how you copy parts of a match into the replacement?

Comment: My knowledge of capture groups and back references is limited. I'll look them up. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use capture groups to copy parts of the input to the result.

```
sed -r -i "s/([a-zA-Z ])'([a-zA-Z ])/\1''\2/g" file.sql
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this in `awk`. Simple explanation would be, perform substitution on last field of line, where substitute `'` with 2 instances of `'` and print the line then.

```
awk '{sub(/\047/,"&&",$NF)} 1' Input_file
```

Above code will only print the lines in output, in case you want to perform inplace save then try following.

```
awk '{sub(/\047/,"&&",$NF)} 1' Input_file > temp && mv temp Input_file
```